# Accessing multiple models in xml view with openUI5

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, sapui5

In my controller I'm setting my models with a name:

```
var oModel = new JSONModel();
oModel.setData({
    delimiterDRS1: " - ",
    dateValueDRS1: dateFrom,
    secondDateValueDRS1: dateTo,
    dateFormatDRS1: "dd/MM/yy"
});
oView.setModel(oModel, "dateRange");
```

and in my xml view I've tried

```
<Text text="{dateRange>dateValueDRS1}"></Text>
<Text text="{/dateRange/dateValueDRS1}"></Text>
```

and neither of those work. I've even tried to set the model globally by doing

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "dateRange")
```

If I don't specify a model name in the setModel method and try to access the attributes {/dateValueDRS1} it works.  I've been looking for documentation but haven't been able to find any. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to read the property by using `"{dateRange>/dateValueDRS1}"`.
The way you read it, would work in a relative path. Check the documentation topic *[Binding Path](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/2888af49635949eca14fa326d04833b9)*.